# visual basic multiple input boxes i only need 1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Why do I keep getting two input boxes instead of one? What am I doing wrong? Is it how I am passing values through functions? If so, how can I fix this?

```
 Private Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click

            'Dim ready_ship As Integer = GetInStock()

            Dim display_spools As Integer = ReadyToShip()
            Dim display_backOrders As Integer = BackOrdered()


            lbl_rship.Text = display_spools.ToString()
            lbl_backo.Text = display_backOrders.ToString()





        End Sub
        Function GetInStock() As Integer


            Dim amount_Spools As String = Nothing

            amount_Spools = InputBox(" Enter the number of spools currently in stock: ")

            Return CInt(amount_Spools)


        End Function
        Function ReadyToShip() As Integer
            Dim ready_ship As Integer = GetInStock()
            Dim a As Integer

            a = CInt(ready_ship)

            Return a
        End Function
        Function BackOrdered() As Integer
            Dim b As Integer = ReadyToShip()
            Dim c As Integer
            c = b - CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            Return c
        End Function




    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Calculate_Click event is calling ReadyToShip() and BackOrdered() functions which are both going to GetInStock() function, which is displaying the input box. So it will be displayed twice.

Answer (score 0):

This class would be better served using properties, they are easier to manage and will help avoid this kind of method duplication.